ReactQuill imageHandler Function Fails to Insert Image in Text Editor
I tried to restrict the quill to allow only one image, and also when an image is uploaded, it automatically adds a line-break, but when i ran the code, the input box of the quill disappears after uploading an image.
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import newD from "./NewDiscussion.module.css";
import "./switch.css";
import "./normalND.css";
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";

function NewDiscussion({ handleClose }) {
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const quillRef = useRef(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsSubmitting(true);

    const formData = {
      title: title.trim(),
      category: document.getElementById("category-select").value,
      tags: document.getElementById("tags-select").value,
      description: content,
    };

    try {
      // Placeholder: replace with your actual API call
      const response = await fetch("your-api-endpoint", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      });
      const result = await response.json();
      console.log(result); // Handle success
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error submitting form:", error);
    }

    setIsSubmitting(false);
    handleClose();
  };

  const imageHandler = () => {
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "file");
    input.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");
    input.click();

    input.onchange = async () => {
      const file = input.files[0];
      if (file) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = () => {
          const base64image = reader.result;
          const editor = quillRef.current.getEditor();
          const range = editor.getSelection(true);
          if (range) {
            editor.insertEmbed(range.index, "image", base64image);
            editor.insertText(range.index + 1, "\n");
            editor.setSelection(range.index + 2, 0);
          }
          setContent(editor.root.innerHTML);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    };
  };

  const modules = {
    toolbar: {
      container: [
        ["bold", "italic", "underline"],
        [{ list: "bullet" }, { list: "ordered" }],
        ["link", "image"],
      ],
      handlers: {
        image: imageHandler,
      },
    },
  };

  const formats = [
    "bold",
    "italic",
    "underline",
    "list",
    "bullet",
    "link",
    "image",
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <div className={newD.openComposer}>
        <div className={newD.manupulateButton}>
          <div className={newD.switchContainer}>
            <p>Anonymous</p>
            <input
              id="cmn-toggle-4"
              className="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round-flat"
              type="checkbox"
            />
            <label htmlFor="cmn-toggle-4"></label>
          </div>
          <div className={newD.rightIcons}>
            <div className={newD.close} onClick={handleClose}>
              <i className="fa-solid fa-x"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={newD.editorCont}>
          <div className={newD.textAreaColumn}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={title}
                onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="What is this discussion about in one brief sentence?"
              />
              <div className={newD.selectContainer}>
                <select name="category" id="category-select">
                  <option value="">--Select a category--</option>
                  <option value="Ideas">Ideas</option>
                  <option value="Academics and Career">
                    Academics and Career
                  </option>
                  <option value="Cultural Exchange">Cultural Exchange</option>
                  <option value="Student Support">Student Support</option>
                  <option value="Events and Activities">
                    Events and Activities
                  </option>
                  <option value="Advocacy and Awareness">
                    Advocacy and Awareness
                  </option>
                  <option value="Networking and Collaboration">
                    Networking and Collaboration
                  </option>
                  <option value="Travel and Exploration">
                    Travel and Exploration
                  </option>
                </select>
                <select name="tags" id="tags-select">
                  <option value="">--Optional Tags--</option>
                  <option value="Help">Help</option>
                  <option value="Information">Information</option>
                  <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
                  <option value="Volunteering">Volunteering</option>
                  <option value="Internships">Internships</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div className={newD.richTextEditorRow}>
                <ReactQuill
                  theme="snow"
                  value={content}
                  onChange={setContent}
                  modules={modules}
                  formats={formats}
                  style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
                  ref={quillRef}
                />
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default NewDiscussion;

Allow only one image and after uploading the image, add a line break to the quill editor.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
